# Count and replace values in factor variable in r

Tags: r

I have a column with 1500 rows.
The rows contain seven different factor levels, but there is only one which i want to target.
If that target appears once and/or is repeated up to 8 rows, i want to change those rows to the row value before the target resp. the repetition of the target started.

data:

```
set.seed(234)
var <- sample(1:7, 1500, replace = TRUE)
var <- factor(var, labels = c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "target", "seven"))
data <- data.frame(var)
```

Comment: Can you please share with us you data `dput(yourDataFrame)` and share your code tentative

Comment: i can just slightly imagine what the code would be, but putting everything together is really my problem